# Recursion depth error in simple Python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I am new to programming, and was trying to solve [this problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=31) on Project Euler using basic Python.

Essentially, I tried to use recursion based on the largest value chosen at every stage, and using a list to maintain possible options for future choices.

The code is short and is given below:

```
def func(n,l):
    if n<0:
        return 0
    if l==[1] or n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        j=0
        while l != []:
            j=j+func(n-l[0],l) 
            del l[0]
        return j

print func(200,[200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1])
```

For instance, if we have

```
func(5,[5,2,1])
```

the recursion splits it into

```
func(0,[5,2,1]) + func(3,[2,1]) + func(4,[1])
```

But the code never seems to go through. Either it says that there is a `list-index-out-of-range` error, or a `maximum-recursion-depth` error (even for very small toy instances). I am unable to find the mistake. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python lists are passed into functions by reference, but not by value. The simplest fix for your program is changing recursive call to `func(n - l[0], l[:])`. In this way list will be passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you're failing to take into account is that the following:

```
j=j+func(n-l[0],l)
```

doesn't make a copy of `l`.

Therefore all recursive invocations of `func` operate on the same list. When the innermost invocation deletes the last element of `l` and returns, its caller will attempt to `del l[0]` and will get an `IndexError`.

Comment: I understand the problem now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At each recursion, make the following 2 decisions:

1. Take the first coin (say `f`) from available coin types, then check if we can made (n-f) from those coins. This results in a sub-problem func(n - f, l)
2. Ignore the first coin type, and check if we can make n from the remaining coin types. This results in a sub-problem func(n, l[1:])

The total number of combinations should be the sum of the two sub-problems. So the code goes:

```
def func(n, l):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n < 0 or len(l) == 0:
        return 0
    if l == [1] or n == 0:
        return 1

    return func(n - l[0], l) + func(n, l[1:])
```

Each recursion a copy of `l` is made by `l[1:]`. This can be omitted by `pop` element before next recursion and restore with `append` afterwards.

```
def func(n, l):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n < 0 or len(l) == 0:
        return 0
    if l == [1] or n == 0:
        return 1

    full = func(n - l[-1], l)
    last = l.pop()
    partial = func(n, l)
    l.append(last)
    return full + partial
```

Comment: Yeah, I had used the same method as you suggested above, but the error arose from referring to the list, as was pointed out. The simple fix suggested in the previous answer (namely replacing j=j+func(n-l[0],l) with j=j+func(n-l[0],l[:]) resolved the problem. But thanks for your solution too!